# Microsoft Academic API, Knowledge graph search -- retrieved paper empty

Tags: json, web-services, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the [graph search](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/57e3569ddbe2d91158fa270e) method of the Microsoft Academic API to retrieve papers by ID using the following query:

```
{
    "path": "/paper",
    "paper": {
        "type": "Paper",
        "id": [2557283755],
        "select": [
            "PublishYear",
            "CitationCount",
            "OriginalTitle",
            "NormalizedTitle",
            "DOI"
        ]
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that for some papers the response is completely empty, even though when I lookup the paper through the user interface, it has full metadata. For example, trying to retrieve [this paper](https://academic.microsoft.com/#/detail/2557283755) through the API yields

```
{
    "Results": [
        [
            {
                "CellID": 2557283755,
                "PublishYear": "",
                "CitationCount": "",
                "OriginalTitle": "",
                "NormalizedTitle": "",
                "DOI": ""
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

while for a different paper the response is correct:

```
{
    "Results": [
        [
            {
                "CellID": 2112796928,
                "PublishYear": "1998",
                "CitationCount": "135",
                "OriginalTitle": "Gradient-based learning applied to document recognition",
                "NormalizedTitle": "gradient based learning applied to document recognition",
                "DOI": "10.1109/5.726791"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? To me it looks like an error in the database, but I wanted to make sure it's not something related to my query. Thanks!

Comment: if it helps. I can confirm the error using their testing console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by data version difference. The version of the academic graph data set used by graph search method might not be the same as that of Microsoft Academic portal https://academic.microsoft.com. We are deploying a new data pipeline to make the version difference as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any way I could be notified when new versions of the API/dataset are released?